# MongoDB query in java for array fields using ProjectionOperation

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, aggregate, projection

Below is the JSON structure for a Store document:

```
{
    {
        "_id":"87348378",
        "name": "ABC store",
        "type": "Books",
        "books": [
        {
            "name": "love",
            "id": "1",
            "types":{
                "type":"love",
                "number":"1"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "coreman",
            "id": "2",
            "types":{
                "type":"love",
                "number":"1"
            }
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id":"87348",
        "name": "Some store",
        "type": "Books",
        "books": [
        {
            "name": "JAVA",
            "id": "1",
            "types":{
                "type":"Programming",
                "number":"2"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "coreman",
            "id": "2",
            "types":{
                "type":"Programming",
                "number":"3"
            }
        }
        ]
    }

}
```

I need to get the all the stores, which are of a *Bookstore type*. But, I just want to **return certain fields** from the Books array(**Name &  type *from types***)

Using the following query to get the result:

```
db.getCollection('store').aggregate([{
 "$project" : { "name" : 1 , "type" : 1 , 
                "books":{"name":1,"types":{"type":1}}}
                }, 
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$type",
    "books" : { "$push" : "$$ROOT"}}}])
```

Could anyone help me out to generate the same query with Spring/Java.

Note: I have seen addInclude method has like below in spring docs.

**reference**: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/ProjectionOperation.html

```
**org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation**

andInclude

public ProjectionOperation andInclude(String... fieldNames)

Includes the given fields into the projection.

Parameters:
    fieldNames - must not be null.
Returns:

andInclude

public ProjectionOperation andInclude(Fields fields)

Includes the given fields into the projection.

Parameters:
    fields - must not be null.
Returns:
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of java query ?

Comment: @Veeram  it's like new ProjectionOperation().andInclude("name","type")